# How to use exact words in NLTK RegexpParser

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to extract specific phrases from text with a help of NLTK RegexpParser.
Is there a way to combine exact word in pos_tags?

For example, this is my text:

```
import nltk

text = "Samle Text and sample Text and text With University of California and Institute for Technology with SAPLE TEXT"

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged_text = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

regex = "ENTITY:{<University|Institute><for|of><NNP|NN>}"

# searching by regex that is defined
entity_search = nltk.RegexpParser(regex)
entity_result = entity_search.parse(tagged_text)
entity_result = list(entity_result)
print(entity_result)
```

Ofc, I have a lot of different combinations of words that I want to use in my "ENTITY" regex, and I have much longer text.
Is there a way to make it work?
FYI, I want to make it work with RegexpParser, I do not want to use regular regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't require you specify exact words and still extracts the entities of interest. The RegExp (`{<N.*><IN><N.*>}`) matches any noun-related tag `<N.*>`, followed by a preposition or subordinating conjunction tag `<IN>`, followed by another noun-related tag `<N.*>`. This is the general PoS tag pattern of strings like of "University of ____" or "Institute for _____". You can make this more strict to match only proper nouns by changing `<N.*>` to be `<NNP>`. For more information on PoS tags, see [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/partofspeechhelp/home).

### Solution #1

```py
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser

text = "This is sample text with the University of California and Institute for Technology with more sample text."
tokenized = word_tokenize(text)  # Tokenize text
tagged_text = pos_tag(tokenized)  # Tag tokenized text with PoS tags

# Create custom grammar rule to find occurrences of a noun followed proposition or subordinating conjunction, followed by another noun (e.g. University of ___)
my_grammar = r"""
ENTITY: {<N.*><IN><N.*>}"""


# Function to create parse tree using custom grammar rules and PoS tagged text
def get_parse_tree(grammar, pos_tagged_text):
    cp = RegexpParser(grammar)
    parse_tree = cp.parse(pos_tagged_text)
    parse_tree.draw()  # Visualise parse tree
    return parse_tree


# Function to get labels from custom grammar:
# takes line separated NLTK regexp grammar rules
def get_labels_from_grammar(grammar):
    labels = []
    for line in grammar.splitlines()[1:]:
        labels.append(line.split(":")[0])
    return labels


# Function takes parse tree & list of NLTK custom grammar labels as input
# Returns phrases which match
def get_phrases_using_custom_labels(parse_tree, custom_labels_to_get):
    matching_phrases = []
    for node in parse_tree.subtrees(filter=lambda x: any(x.label() == custom_l for custom_l in custom_labels_to_get)):
        # Get phrases only, drop PoS tags
        matching_phrases.append([leaf[0] for leaf in node.leaves()])
    return matching_phrases


text_parse_tree = get_parse_tree(my_grammar, tagged_text)
my_labels = get_labels_from_grammar(my_grammar)
phrases = get_phrases_using_custom_labels(text_parse_tree, my_labels)

for phrase in phrases:
    print(phrase)
```

### Output

[image: Custom parse tree]

```
['University', 'of', 'California']
['Institute', 'for', 'Technology']
```

If you really require the ability to capture exact words, you can do this by defining custom tags for each of the words you require. One crude solution to do this without training your own custom tagger is as follows:

### Solution #2

```py
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, RegexpParser

text = "This is sample text with the University of California and Institute for Technology with more sample text."
tokenized = word_tokenize(text)  # Tokenize text
tagged_text = pos_tag(tokenized)  # Tag tokenized text with PoS tags

# Define custom tags for specific words
my_specific_tagged_words = {
    "ORG_TYPE": ["University", "Institute"],
    "PREP": ["of", "for"]
}

# Create copy of tagged text to modify with custom tags
modified_tagged_text = tagged_text

# Iterate over tagged text, find the specified words and then modify the tags
for i, text_tag_tuple in enumerate(tagged_text):
    for tag in my_specific_tagged_words.keys():
        for word in my_specific_tagged_words[tag]:
            if text_tag_tuple[0] == word:
                modified_tagged_text[i] = (word, tag) # Modify tag for specific word

# Create custom grammar rule to find occurrences of ORG_TYPE tag, followed PREP tag, followed by another noun
my_grammar = r"""
ENTITY: {<ORG_TYPE><PREP><N.*>}"""


# Copy previously defined get_parse_tree, get_labels_from_grammar, get_phrases_using_custom_labels functions here...


text_parse_tree = get_parse_tree(my_grammar, tagged_text)
my_labels = get_labels_from_grammar(my_grammar)
phrases = get_phrases_using_custom_labels(text_parse_tree, my_labels)

for phrase in phrases:
    print(phrase)
```

### Output

[image: Custom parse tree with custom tags]

```
['University', 'of', 'California']
['Institute', 'for', 'Technology']
```